# A CGAffineTransform with rotation and translation, what different?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cgaffinetransform

There are:

1.

`CGAffineTransform layerTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI_2);`

`layerTransform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(layerTransform, 1080, 0);`

2.

`CGAffineTransform layerTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(1080, 0);`

`layerTransform = CGAffineTransformRotate(layerTransform, M_PI_2);`

What's the different between them ?

Rotate before or after translate, is there any different?

Comment: it depends on which the coordinate system you are using; as in world-coordinate system they are _not_ commutative, but in the object's local coordinate system they _may_ be commutative.

Answer (score 0):

**CGAffineTransformTranslate** is basically create a new affine transform by translating (moving) existing affine transform with specified method. We have to use `CGAffineTransform CGAffineTransformTranslate ( CGAffineTransform t, CGFloat tx, CGFloat ty )` method for it. Here `tx` and `ty` has the values by which new affine transform have to move in X and Y direction respectively.

**CGAffineTransformRotate** is basically create a new affine transform by rotating existing transform with specified method. We have to use `CGAffineTransform CGAffineTransformRotate ( CGAffineTransform t, CGFloat angle )` method for it. Here `angle` has the rotation angle for new affine transform.

I hope, you can get that first one is used to get a shift from one position to another one, and second one is used to get a roation.

Answer (score 0):

The thing you need to know is that translation means move the location. 
Rotation is self explanatory. 
The order does matter depending on the origin point and the effect you want to achieve. 
I'm Core Graphics this is lower left on a OS X and upper left on iOS. 
In Core Animation objects can be transformed more easily by their center points.

CG works with rects though. 
The most common hurtful thing is trying to rotate something about its center in CG. 
If you just rotate transform the thing will appear to rotate around its origin like the hand of a clock. 
So if you move the origin then rotate, you you can compensate for this. 
The math is not easy unless you know trig and radians. 
The trick is that you need to apply both transformations before drawing again or the thing will jump about.